# How to unit-test/mock C binding implementation in Go?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

I would like to implement a unit-test for this implementation:

```
import "C"

// Model represents a TensorFlow Lite Model.
type Model struct {
    model *C.TfLiteModel
}

// NewModelFromFile creates a new TensorFlow Lite Model from File.
func NewModelFromFile(path string) (*Model, error) {
    m := C.TfLiteModelCreateFromFile(C.CString(path))
    if m == nil {
        return nil, ErrCreateModel
    }
    return &Model{model: m}, nil
}
```

I tried to use [Testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify) to implement an idea using a mock, but I don know how to manipulate the interaction with the C binding.

Any idea that how is the best strategy to do unit-test for this type of code structure?